# Why, according to the ta.barssince function, it is not possible to build a line

Tags: pine-script

I want to build 2 lines in a given range from the first bar to 10. The first one is built without problems between the Low of the first bar and the Low of the 10th bar. I want to build a second line between the Maximum price and the minimum price in the same range. However, when bar_index is found, an error occurs and the line is drawn incorrectly.

```
//@version=5
strategy("9000", overlay=true, default_qty_value=100, margin_long=100, margin_short=100)

if hour == 00 and minute == 00
    line.new(x1=bar_index[10], y1=low[10], x2=bar_index[0], y2=low[0], width=4, color=color.green)
    bar_index_Max = ta.barssince(high == ta.highest(high, 10))
    bar_index_Min = ta.barssince(low == ta.lowest(low, 10))
    _high = high[bar_index_Max]
    _low = low[bar_index_Min]
    line.new(x1=bar_index[bar_index_Max], y1=_high, x2=bar_index[bar_index_Min], y2=low[_low], width=2)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You set `y2` to `y2=low[_low]`. That means you are trying to refer to `y2`'s value `_low` bars ago. Now, `_low` is probably a very big number depending on your ticker.

Let's say you are on BTC. Then `_low` would be something around 24k right now. Your expression then says give me the `low` value from 24k bars ago.

Also, pay attention to the warning messages.

```
line 6: The function 'ta.barssince' should be called on each calculation for consistency. It is recommended to extract the call from this scope
line 6: The function 'ta.highest' should be called on each calculation for consistency. It is recommended to extract the call from this scope
line 7: The function 'ta.barssince' should be called on each calculation for consistency. It is recommended to extract the call from this scope
line 7: The function 'ta.lowest' should be called on each calculation for consistency. It is recommended to extract the call from this scope
```

There is no need for those functions to be in a local scope.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I'll figure it out further.